# TextView OnClickListener not responding in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm new to this fragment coding in Android stuff so I hope this is a simple one for most to answer.

I have a TextView object, 'next', that, when clicked, does not seem to be responding.  I want to do a few things when the TextView text is clicked.  First, check the String value in the eventName spinner, then Toast the eventID value and finally start a new fragment for the next part of user interaction.

I have not yet implemented the new fragment or a call to the fragment.  I assume the way to call the new fragment is with the following code:

```
NextFragment nextFrag= new NextFragment();
     getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
     .replace(R.id.Layout_container, nextFrag,"findThisFragment")
     .addToBackStack(null)
     .commit();
```

My questions are:

1. Why is the Toast not being displayed?  It seems as though the OnCickListener or the OnClick method isn't triggering the Toast.
2. Is the code above all that I need to do to call a new fragment and make it active in the current Activity or is there something else that I need to add in the Activity code?

Fragment code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link FindEventFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link FindEventFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class FindEventFragment extends Fragment{

    public static final String TAG = "FindEventFragment";
    private VolleyHelper mInstance;
    private ArrayList<String> eventList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private JSONArray result;
    private Spinner eventNameSpinner;
    private TextView eventDate;
    private String eventID;
    private TextView next;
    //TextView errorText;

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public FindEventFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment FindEventFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static FindEventFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FindEventFragment fragment = new FindEventFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Instantiate the RequestQueue from VolleyHelper
        mInstance = VolleyHelper.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        // API
        connectApi();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop () {
        super.onStop();
        if (mInstance.getRequestQueue() != null) {
            mInstance.getRequestQueue().cancelAll(TAG);
        }
    }

    private void connectApi() {
        String url = "http://gblakes.ddns.net/get_events.php";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String ServerResponse) {

                        JSONObject j = null;
                        try {
                            result = new JSONArray(ServerResponse);
                            eventDetails(result);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                       Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Oops, something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        if (mInstance != null) {
            // Add a request to your RequestQueue.
            mInstance.addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
            // Start the queue
            mInstance.getRequestQueue().start();
        }
    }

    private void eventDetails(JSONArray j) {
        eventList.add("Choose an event");
        for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);
                // eventList.add(json.getString("EventName") + json.getString("EventDate"));
                eventList.add(json.getString("EventName"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
            }
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, eventList);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        eventNameSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        eventNameSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                //Setting the value to textview for a selected item
                eventDate.setText(getEventDate(position));
                eventID = (getEventID(position));
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                eventDate.setText("test me");
            }
        });
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                //Make sure the user has made a valid selection
                //errorText.setError("");
                if (eventNameSpinner.equals("Choose an event")){
                    //errorText.setError("");
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Choose an event first",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    //errorText.setText("Choose an event first");
                } else {
                    //if an event is selected then open the next fragment
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),eventID.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private String getEventID(int position) {
        String eventID = "";
        try {
            //Getting object of given index
            JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(position);
            //Fetching name from that object
            eventID = json.getString("EventID");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Returning the name
        return eventID;
    }

    private String getEventDate(int position){
        String eventDate="";
        try {
            JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(position);
            eventDate = json.getString("EventDate");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return eventDate;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_event,container,false);
        eventNameSpinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinEventPicker);
        //eventNameSpinner = new Spinner(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        eventDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textEventDate);
        next = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.link_judgeToEvent);
        eventDate.setText("test me");
//        errorText = (TextView)eventNameSpinner.getSelectedView();

        return v;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(eventID);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(String eventID);
    }
}
```

and the fragment's XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/textEventName">
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinEventPicker"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textEventDate"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinEventPicker"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/link_judgeToEvent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textEventDate"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Next"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="16dip" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toast will display if you call show(), So you have to change the following line of code like this

```
 Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Choose an event first",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You can use the following code  sample code to launch the fragment from another fragment

```
    Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment1, fragment2);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: OMG how could I be so stupid!!  Ive used Toast a million times and never forgotten to use the show() method.  Guess Im in desperate need of a coding break.  Thank you and thanks for the code sample :)